# Text and image positioning with css

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with positioning a text with an image using CSS. It works good in Firefox and IE but not in Safari. The image is placed left of the text and I want the text to be in the center of the image in vertical positioning. I'm using a custom font (MyriadProLight), using font-face.

This is how it looks in Safari:
http://oi52.tinypic.com/2eg5p8x.jpg

This is how I want it (and how it looks in Firefox and IE):
http://oi54.tinypic.com/1zg3xhx.jpg

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>

            @font-face {
            font-family: 'MyriadProLight';
            src: url('myriadpro-light-webfont.eot');
            src: local('☺'), url('myriadpro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('myriadpro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('myriadpro-light-webfont.svg#webfontpR0gSEvM') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            }

            h1 
            {
                font-size: 20pt;
                font-family: "MyriadProLight", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #333;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                line-height: 21pt;
                font-weight: normal;
                letter-spacing: 0px;
                margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .iconimage
            {
                margin-right: 7px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><img class="iconimage" src="image.png" />This is the header</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The entire page code plays a role here.  Can you post ALL the HTML?

Comment: @KatieK - Updated the question, but it's really simple html as I have been testing this a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positioning images inline with text is a messy business. I would move the image outside of your h1 tag and float it left, then tweak placement with margins. Something like this:

```
<img class="iconimage" src="mail.png" style="float:left; margin:10px" />
<h1>This is the header</h1>
```

Comment: Ok, I thought of that solution but wanted to get it inside if that was possible..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this adds anything, but if you view your page in Firefox and then use firebug to hunt down the element, you may notice that an @font-face web fonts are not lined up vertically in the centre of their line-heights. I don't know enough about fonts to know whether this is a font-file issue, but I did all my generation with font-squirrel, which people seem to think is the most reliable option.

WORKAROUNDS

My font ('Destroy') was lined up very heavily toward the bottom. So if I didn't include enough space for it, it looked chopped off at the bottom. Two solutions worked:

1. If your element is non-breaking: Make the line-height double the font-size.
2. If your element breaks: add padding to the bottom of the element equal to or slightly less than the font-size.

Obviously (or maybe not so, sorry), I'm dealing with headers and such. I have no idea if these would work with paragraphs or other multi-lined elements.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to SO! Please keep in mind that answers are not posts and we therefore try not to include salutations, taglines, or signatures. Also, I suggest you read the [faq].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be best to remove the img tag and do it in CSS alone:

```
h1 {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    background: url(image.png) no-repeat left;
}
```